# Getting error in XDEBUG

Tags: linux, debian, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I just installed xdebug on my eclipse PDT installation and now I am getting the following error when trying to debug my PHP code using XDEBUG on my local debian box:

web launch already running

2 questions:

1. How can I kill this within Eclipse without getting out of Eclipse all together?
2. Is there an additional configuration setting that needs to be set that were not in my instructions?

Any help/direction would be appreciated as I'm at the point where I'm starting to pull my hair out.  Thanks!

Here is what I added to my php.ini file in the Dynamic Extensions section per instructions:

```
;load module
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"

;some options
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

;The following IP should be of the host running Eclipse!
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=

;Only enable the following if you want profiler output (lots of data!)
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/log/XDebug/
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
```

Comment: Your Xdebug configuration looks fine. This error messages comes from PDT (and I've no idea what to do about it).

Comment: Thanks, Derick. I could never get the PDT version of Eclipse to work with XDEBUG. I finally got figured out how to terminate my XDEBUG session just by terminating my session in Debug mode.  I guess XDEBUG just did not know how to terminate itself.  I had to go to Netbeans and even though it's pretty huge it worked great with my XDEBUG installation. No add'l configurations were required.  It was great!  Again, thanks for your reply back on 5/3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Web Launch Already Running"
It means that you have started the debug session already and it is not being terminated yet.
Open 'Debug' perspective and see 'Debug' tab, select 'PHP Web Application' and click 'Terminate'(red square) button.